# Change font for \usepackage{listing}

Tags: listings

I have the following tex file :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\lstset{
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  ={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  =\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Third median in terms of $\theta$ and $\phi$},label={lst:f4}]
p, t= var('p t') 
a=(-2*p*t^2-p^2*t)+(2*t*p-p^2)+t+1 
b=(p*t^2+2*p^2*t)+(2*t*p-t^2)-p+1 
c=(p*t^2-p^2*t)+(t^2+2*t*p+p^2)+t-p #3 sides (a,b,c) in terms of theta and phi
expand(2*a^2+2*b^2-c^2) #third median equation, m=1/2*sqrt(2*a^2+2*b^2-c^2)
        9*p^4*t^2 + 18*p^3*t^3 + 9*p^2*t^4 + 6*p^4*t + 18*p^3*t^2 - 18*p^2*t^3 -
         6*p*t^4 + p^4 - 22*p^3*t + 6*p^2*t^2 - 22*p*t^3 + t^4 + 2*p^3 - 6*p^2*t
         + 6*p*t^2 - 2*t^3 - 3*p^2 + 18*p*t - 3*t^2 - 4*p + 4*t + 4
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I want to change the font of the listings to be smaller, probably `\tiny`. Can anyone guide me how to do it.

Comment: Hi Shahrina. I can't compile your source with Papeeria or Overleaf because there are many LaTeX Error, Undefined control sequence and others errors.

Comment: sorry I will edit the tex file.

Comment: something is missing before `={\small\ttfamily}` and `=\color{blue}`. You probably wanted to say `basicstyle={\small\ttfamily}`. If it's correct, replace `\small` by `\tiny` and you'll get an smaller typeface.

Comment: @Ignasi Sorry, I didn't see your comment before I posted my answer, if you want to answer I can delete mine.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. No problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `basicstyle` key is probably what you're after, i.e.

```
\lstset{
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
...
}
```

`\ttfamily` is assuming you want to use the typewriter font. For smaller font than `\small`, replace `\small` with `\footnotesize`, `\scriptsize` or `\tiny`, depending on what you want.

There seems to be some keys missing from the `key=value` pairs in your `lstset`, you have `={\small\ttfamily}` (which might be where you wanted `basicstyle`), and later `=\color{blue}`, though I don't what that was intended for, of course.